# viaRequest method with api driver is not working in Lumen Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth, lumen, laravel-passport

I am implementing Passport in Lumen to authenticate users and APIs using Lumen 10.0 and dusterio/lumen-passport. I followed the articles on the internet to implement it but I stuck at authentication in `AuthServiceProvider`. In the boot method viaRequest() is not executing. I have enabled `$app->configure('auth')` and `$app->routeMiddleware([ 'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class, ])` in bootstrap/app.php.

Here is my Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        LumenPassport::routes($this->app);
       
        var_dump('outside');    //working
        $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            var_dump('inside'); // not working
            if ($request->header('Authorization')) {
                $key = explode(' ', $request->header('Authorization'))[1];
                return User::where('api_token', $key)->first();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My config/auth.php

```
<?php 

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Models\User::class
        ],
    ]
];
```

Here is the route

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function ($router) {
        $router->get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
        $router->get('logout', 'UserController@logout');
    });
```

I have tried everything by changing *api* driver value in viaRequest() method to *passport* driver then it executes the function but then my *logout* route does not work to get the access token. I don't know why the *viaRequest()* is not working with *api* driver value.